# Using python CGIHTTPServer to export d3 svg

Tags: python, perl, d3.js

I'd like to export the svg from a d3 chart to a .svg file without requiring any interaction from the user. I'm using code based on this great example :

http://d3export.cancan.cshl.edu/

but server side scripting is new to me and when I try to run the example code using my built in python CGIHTTPServer, I get "Error code 501. Message: Can only POST to CGI scripts. Error code explanation: 501 = Server does not support this operation."

My question is: should the python CGI server be able to handle the downloading of the svg file based on this example (perl code below)?  If not, are there any other simple alternatives to test this?

Thank you! Carrie

download.pl looks like this:

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;
use autodie qw(:all);
use File::Temp qw/tempfile/;
use File::Slurp qw/read_file write_file/;

print header(-type=>"image/svg+xml",
     -attachment=>"d3js_export_demo.svg");    
print $data;
exit(0);
```

** Update **
I did not get the above code working using my local python CGI server (CGIHTTPServer). I did get a simpler version of the same code (see below) working on a remote server. This version also did not work on my local CGIHTTPServer, so for now I'm resigned to using the remote server for development.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI qw/:standard/;

my $counter = param('num');
# input validation
my $data = param('data')
or die "Missing 'data' parameter";

print header(-type => "image/svg+xml",
-attachment => "d3demo$counter.svg");
print $data;
exit(0);
```